# I have a blocking API that requires a reactive component now. Is this the correct way to implement it?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Here's my blocking method signature

```
public void unmodifiableAPI(String foobar) {
  if( Condition.validate(foobar) == false ) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

Suppose my `Condition.validate()` becomes reactive

```
public class Condition {
  public static Single<Boolean> validate(String foobar) { ... }
}
```

Is this ok way to rewrite the API implementation?

```
public void unmodifiableAPI(String foobar) {
  Condition.validate(foobar)
    .filter(isOk -> !isOk)
    .flatMap(isOk -> Maybe.error(new RuntimeException())
    .subscribe();
  }
}
```

This seems to work for me in a toy example, but what I'm afraid of is that after I subscribe to that Single, then I won't be able to use it again.

Should I instead convert it to a Future and run it from a dedicated threadpool instead?

Comment: Your updated method won't throw the RuntimeException anymore and may crash your Android app instead. Also it may return while the `validate` hasn't even finished. You could return `Maybe` and keep composing other operators. What's the greater context behind this `unmodifiableAPI`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm getting the impression it's impossible to work with reactive objects in a blocking call without calling block() at some point, which is a big no-no